# Is this call from "the Treasury Department" an attempted identity theft?

Tags: tax-law, fraud, identity-theft

I got a phone message in which a robotic voice identified itself as the Treasury Department, contacting me about some matter related to my taxes, and saying if I didn't reply I could be arrested.  Is there any chance at all that's legitimate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking whether someone is committing a crime. We can't evaluate rules or policies of organizations, public or not, and this is a site for discussing law, not policy. It's far better to look to the actual organization itself for such an answer.

Comment: The US government NEVER calls saying pay or be arrested. They either send a letter or show up in vehicles BUT THEY NEVER CALL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are almost exactly zero that this is a legitimate call.  However, if you would like to verify that with the Department of the Treasury, they have a fraud hotline at 1-800-359-3898, which you can find on [their contact us page](https://www.treasury.gov/connect/Pages/contact-us.aspx).

Assume any information they give you is false, and only contact the Department of the Treasury (or any other agency/company) though numbers listed on their website.  If the scammers continue to harrass you, you can report them to your local police.

Comment: It's worth adding to this post then when you call the Department after a suspected spam phone call to find out if it is legit, make sure to do so from a landline connection, or at the very least a different phone from the one you were called on. There have been many cases of scammers calling someone, that person trying to call the police, and the spammer intercepting the call, acting as the police, and confirming what the scammer said.